# iPod music should stop playing when launching app

Tags: ios, xcode, playback

How can I make my app automatically stop the iPod music - if it's playing - as soon as the app is started?
I need this so when people listen to music and want to use the app they don't need to pause the music first before opening the app.

Comment: Just guessing around: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475034/how-to-stop-and-resume-background-audio-from-iphone-app

Comment: Sorry if my question wasn't clear enough. I'm developing an app for iPhones with Xcode and I wanted that app to pause the iPod music when it is launched. But thanks anyways!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple enough, import the MediaPlayer framework and tell the `iPodMusicPlayer` to `stop` or `pause`.

```
[[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] stop];
[[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] pause];
```

Comment: Is there also a way to not make the app pause the music suddenly but maybe make it fade out or so. The youtube app makes it like this for example.