# Do not allow other apps play music

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudiosession

We are developing a VOIP application and while there is an active call, we want not to allow other apps play music or something (like Whatsapp does). 
Is there any way of doing it in a normal way, can you help please?

**Edit 1:** 
I think we need to start with listening the observer **AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification**.

**Accepted Answer Edit 2:** 
When sound interruption begins, try to only active the **AudioSession** again. This works. Thank you **KudoCC**.

Comment: Does "the active call" mean the system phone call ? Or your app's VOIP call ? Why do you think observe `AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification` would work?

Comment: It is VOIP call (also reporting to the system with CallKit, iOS 10 feature). If we observe that notification, we can again make AudioSession active and by that take control the phone audio output. But I tried it and it doesn't work.

Comment: Does your app use `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` category ? You can try to re-active your audio session when you're playing/recording audio, if you active the audio session successfully, other app would stop playing.

Comment: Yes we use that category, in fact your advice is the accepted answer. It works thanks. I tried the way that setting the category again as AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord and then activating the session but it didn't work yesterday (it could'nt activate the session so it couldn't stop the other apps music). Only activating the session works :) Thank you.

Comment: Do you mind if I write down my answer?

Comment: Yes, it will be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a link talks about [audio category](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/AudioSessionCategoriesandModes/AudioSessionCategoriesandModes.html), there is a table in it:
[image]

As your app supports VoIP, so it need to play and record audio, and you need interrupt non-mixable apps audio, so `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` is the right category. Also you should re-active your audio session when you're playing/recording audio so that the category takes effect.

Comment: Thanks, re-activating the AudioSession when interruption begins works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your app to pause the background audio when calls,

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO withOptions:AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptionNotifyOthersOnDeactivation error:&error];
```

It is helpful when other apps uses AVAudioPlayer.

For more detail refer [this Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475034/how-to-stop-and-resume-background-audio-from-iphone-app)

Comment: Thanks for helping but your advice is about resuming the other apps music which is not related with my problem.