# Pause / Play background audio from other apps

Tags: ios

I know this is likely way outside of the sandbox but I thought I'd ask anyway:

I want to put a "pause / play" button in my app that will pause or play any background audio. Basically I'm looking to implement the play/pause button found in the multi-task bar.

A simple example is someone stars music with Pandora app, then launches my app. Is it possible to pause the background audio and resume it?

As a curiosity I have wondered if there was a way to create or broadcast the "remote control" events. Can I publish a pause/play event to the OS, perhaps?

Comment: Is a solution that requires jailbreaking acceptable?

Comment: I do not want to have to go te jailbreaking route. If you have a quick pointer I love learning these things. But I think I'll keep the question as an "officially supported way" kind of question.

Answer (score 1):

I think [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448043/resume-background-audio-after-playing-sound-with-avaudioplayer)'s what you're looking for.  The trick is to loop a short audio file with silence when you want the other audio to stop.  Then tell the iOS audio system when you're done, as suggested in the link.

Comment: This is an interesting option. I'm not excited about any added CPU usage by "playing an audio file" this whole time. But maybe I can create an implementation detail for those issues. It's at least a valid solution.

Comment: That is really interesting. I am trying to make sleep timer app. I will try to use your logic

Comment: @Abdullah be aware this worked 8 years ago. Good luck!