# How to resume the audio in ios?

Tags: ios, audio, ios7, avfoundation

I am using `Audioplayer` for playing audio file which is 5-10 secs. My app allows background music of other apps. While playing my audio I am deactivating the other music using

```
 [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES withOptions:AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptionNotifyOthersOnDeactivation error:nil];
```

After completion of my audio, I want to play the deactivated music.

Is this possible in `AVAudioPlayer` & `AVAudioSession`? Or else which framework supports for this resuming functionality?

Comment: I too need answer for this!!!

Comment: Please try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448043/resume-background-audio-after-playing-sound-with-avaudioplayer

Comment: Thank you, but am unable to play after resuming.

Answer (score 6):

After playing your sounds, deactivate your AVAudioSession

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO withOptions:AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptionNotifyOthersOnDeactivation error:nil];
```

Comment: It will stop other music player, but after it wont start playing

Comment: This is the correct answer. However you have no control over whether other apps playing background music are correctly handling the notification that they can resume.\ or ensuring that they have the right permissions in the first place so there is no guarantee that it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I did a bit of searching and found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475034/how-to-stop-and-resume-background-audio-from-iphone-app).

From the linked answer:

> `[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO withFlags:AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptionNotifyOthersOnDeactivation error:&error];`
>   Whenever you do not require the audio session in your application (i.e. when you're not outputting any sound) you should be deactivating it. Where it makes sense, you should use this method so that any background audio is notified and may resume (applications receiving this notification do not necessarily have to resume).

I haven't confirmed it works but it's something to try and I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

@gabuh's answer, translated to Swift:

```
try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(false, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
```

Answer (score -1):

You could make a class for all your audio calls.

Or if you know what's playing, you could save them in an array and play them back out.

The framework doesn't allow you to do what you want.

I recommend making your own wrapper class for any audio calls.